# Merge two column from different table row wise using mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have tables 
**Student**

```
 --------------
| Name | Grade |
 --------------
 --------------
| John |  A+   |
 --------------
| Tina |  B    |
 --------------
```

And **Type**

```
 --------------
| Type | Class |
 --------------
 --------------
| Good |  12   |
 --------------
| Avg  |  11   |
 --------------
```

Now I want to get the result by merging them row-wise so the result of the SQL query would be,

```
 -----------------------------
| Name | Grade | Type | Class |
 -----------------------------
| John |  A+   | Good |  12   |
 -----------------------------
| Tine |  B    | Avg  |  11   |
 -----------------------------
```

Comment: Are there any columns which link the two tables? What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: You need a relationship from Student to Type to get a good and trusted merge.

Comment: There is no relation. That is why I said row wise join.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming there are the same number of columns in each table, you can link them by row number. Without an `ORDER BY` clause though the row numbering is indeterminate and you can't guarantee results.

In MySQL 5.7 and below:

```
SELECT Name, Grade, Type, Class
FROM (SELECT *, @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rownum
      FROM Student
      CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rownum := 0) r
      ) s
JOIN (SELECT *, @rownum2 := @rownum2 + 1 AS rownum
      FROM Type
      CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rownum2 := 0) r
      ) t ON t.rownum = s.rownum
```

In MySQL 8.0 and above:

```
SELECT Name, Grade, Type, Class
FROM (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER () AS rownum
      FROM Student) s
JOIN (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER () rownum
      FROM Type) t ON t.rownum = s.rownum
```

Output:

```
Name    Grade   Type    Class
John    A+      Good    12
Tina    B       Avg     11
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/udiszdmSXJXDEbUHp7yGKP/0)